# Regex replace special comments

Tags: regex, replace

So few months ago one of my colleagues left. He used to comment all his code this way:

```
//----------------------------
// COMMENT
//----------------------------

private void func()...
```

So each comment, instead of using 1 line at most, uses 4 lines (including break line), which drives me crazy. I'm trying to create a Regex which I can remove this comment safely and replace it. The above code should like this way:

```
// COMMENT
private void func()...
```

I thought of just removing each one of the '//----------------------------' but it leaves me with many empty lines as well as break line between the comment and the actual line which to be described. Any help will be well appreciated.

**EDIT**

**Note one:**
Our project is written in Visual Studio

**Note two:** Some comments may contain more than 1 line of comment, example:

```
//----------------------------
// LINE 1 COMMENT
// LINE 2 COMMENT
//----------------------------
```

Comment: And did you try adding `\r\n` to the search string?

Comment: ^^^^ and to remove multiple lines, search: `([\r\n])+` and replace by `$1`.

Comment: In addition to other commenters' suggestions, you may need to enable multi-line matching mode for this to work.  How to do that depends on the tool you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression matches your case and any 3 lines of comments where the first and the last ones have trailing `-`:

```
((\s|\t)*\/{2,})(.*[-]+)(\r?\n)((\1(.*)\4?)+)\4\1\3\4?
```

[**Try it here**](https://regex101.com/r/qN1uI5/8)

And then you can replace it with:

```
\5 (or $5)
```

**EDIT:** for multi-line comments.

Comment: In visual studio, would the replace line be: '//$5'?

Comment: In VS `$i` must be used in place of `\i`, where i is a numerical group reference.

Comment: Note that this regex works perfectly. I couldn't use 'replace-all' in the project tho, because I noticed some of the comments did not have a break line between the comment and the described line, and some did. What I did was adding a break line between the line and the comment and then your regex worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Regular Expression that you can use to strip out the excess (decorative) comment lines and convert these bulky comments into one-liners.

It also supports indentation and multi-line comments using this style:

```
//----------------------------
// LINE 1 COMMENT
// LINE 2 COMMENT
//----------------------------

private void func()...
```

**Find:**

```
(( |\t)*?\r\n)?( |\t)*?//-+(\r\n( |\t)*?// .+)+\r\n( |\t)*?//-+\r\n
```

**Replace With:**

```
\4
```

(Replace `\4` with `$4` if the replace failed)

Good luck!

Comment: As you said, while '\2' worked in notepad++ for instance, '$2' worked on VS